# WCF - endpoint not found - error in corporate network

Tags: wpf, wcf

We've deployed a WPF application (.NET 4) to a corporate network. The application doesn't have direct access to the database. The application talks to the database using a WCF service. When the customer tries to login to the application he gets an error

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://oururl/dataportal/wcfportal.svc that could accept the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See inner
>   exception, if present, for more details.

But if the customer tries to login while Fiddler is running in the background, then it all works fine. See the `app.config` file below. Any help to diagnose the issue will be appreciated.

```
<configuration>   
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- ZIP Enabled Dataportal -->
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="gzipMessageEncoding" 
             type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.GZipMessageEncodingElement, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <client>         
      <endpoint name="WcfDataPortal" 
          address="http://oururl/dataportal/wcfportal.svc" 
          binding="customBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="dataportalCompressed" 
          contract="Csla.Server.Hosts.IWcfPortal" />      
      <metadata>
        <policyImporters>
          <extension type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.GZipMessageEncodingBindingElementImporter, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </policyImporters>
      </metadata>
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="dataportalCompressed">
          <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding"/>
          <httpTransport hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
               manualAddressing="False" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" 
               authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="False" 
               realm="" useDefaultWebProxy="True" />         
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SSL_ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that are you able to access the SVC file from browser. There may be proxy issue.

Comment: Yes, the SVC file can be accessed from the browser. Just to clarify, the application works if you try to access from outside the customer's corporate network. From within the network it only works if you have the fiddler running in the background.